# In the first page i was passing the values in textbox then i should get the data in second page in text box using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In the first page entered the values using text box,In second page also it should display in the text box.But it is not displaying like that.......

Below is my first page pass.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">function getParams()
     {
         var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
         var params = new Array();
          if (idx !=-1) 
             {
                 var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1,
                  document.URL.length).split('&');
                  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++)
                      {
                          console.log(pairs.length);
                           nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
                           params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
                         }
                      }
                       return params;
                    }
                      params = getParams();
                      firstname = unescape(params["firstname"]);
                      lastname = unescape(params["lastname"]);
                      age = unescape(params["age"]);
                    document.write("firstname = " + firstname + "<br>");                   
                    document.write("lastname = " + lastname + "<br>");
                    document.write("age = " + age + "<br>");
                   </script>
                 </head>
              </html>
```

And below is my second page pass1.html

```
<html>
  <form type=get action="pass1.html">
    <table>
       <tr>
     <td>First Name:</td>
     <td><input type=text name=firstname size=10></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Last Name:</td>
      <td><input type=text name=lastname size=10></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Age:</td>
      <td><input type=number name=age></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td colspan=2><input type=submit value="Submit">
        </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </form>
   </html>
```

Comment: Data can't be passed from one html to another. You can use **[Local Storage](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)** for storing data on first page and retrieving on second page.

Comment: Okay sir,How can i use Local Storage for sending and retrieving the data?

Comment: If you are using a query string to pass parameters to the second page, you simple parse it and extract the values.

Comment: how does the form look in `pass.html`. You only provided `pass1.html`. Is it exactly same ?